# Using XSLT/XML to generate styles for HTML tags? (xsl:attribute-set)

Tags: css, xslt, attributes, stylesheet, parent-child

Okay, it's been a tough hour or so... I'm having difficulties generating table cells with different widths. I'm using XML/XSLT to spit out my HTML, so basically the widths are stored in XML format:

```
<size>
<width1>5</width1>
<width2>4</width2>
<width3>7</width3>
</size>
```

Using XSLT's attribute-set I should have a table row and cells with 5px, 4px, 7px widths respectively. However, the trouble with this is that `attribute-set` needs to be a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>` for it to work. I CAN'T do this: (forgive the missing px)

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute-set name="style">
            <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="size/width1"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:attribute-set>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute-set name="style">
            <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="size/width2"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:attribute-set>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute-set name="style">
            <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="size/width3"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:attribute-set>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there any way to generate html tag using XML data to style them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of **xsl:attribute-set** you need to add an **xsl:attribute** inside your `<td>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="size">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                <xsl:value-of select="./width1"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </td>

        <td>
            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                <xsl:value-of select="./width2"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </td>

        <td>
            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                <xsl:value-of select="./width3"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

More XSLT style:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="size">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="size/*">
        <td style="width:{.}px;">
            <!-- Do stuff -->
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your sample result will be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:5px;"></td>
        <td style="width:4px;"></td>
        <td style="width:7px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've overlooked templates and didn't learn them... time to hit the books.

Comment: @stockoverflow. Michael Kay's "XSLT. Programmer's reference" is The One.

Comment: Cheers thanks for the suggestion Flack, I'll check my library for a copy.